# Redirect subdomain to Odoo database

Tags: redirect, subdomain, odoo-11

I want to find out if anyone has an idea for doing this:
Indeed, I installed Odoo 11 on an Ubuntu 18 server, and I am trying to do this:
I have a domain www.company.com, and I would like to redirect my demo1 database to demo1.company.com

I have configured Apache so that it redirect to: demo1.company.com/web?db=demo1
But at each this brings me back to the part where we select the databases.

Can you help me configure without having to display the list of databases and be redirected to the login area of demo1.company.com?

Thank you

Comment: related question https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/question/how-to-hide-database-selector-in-odoo-11-127912

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it don't work :(

Comment: @JuanSebastianOcampoOspina i found my solution with this ; https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/11.0/dbfilter_from_header

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `dbfilter` in your `odoo.conf` like so:

```
dbfilter=%d
```

To quote [Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/cmdline.html):

```
--db-filter <filter>

hides databases that do not match <filter>. The filter is a regular expression, with the additions that:

    %h is replaced by the whole hostname the request is made on.

    %d is replaced by the subdomain the request is made on
```